# The volume of an object resulted from a boolean operation is "sometimes" a negative number. Why is this happening?

Tags: mesh, scripting, modifiers

The volume of an object resulted from a boolean operation is "sometimes" a negative number. Why is this happening? If I export this object as an STL file and import it back, the volume of the imported object is properly presented.

Here is what I did.

(1) A boolean operation (intersect) with Object_1 and Object_2

```
b = Object_1.modifiers.new(name='booly', type='BOOLEAN')
b.object = Object_2 
b.operation = 'INTERSECT' 
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply({"object": Object_1},apply_as='DATA',modifier=b.name)
```

(2) Calculating the volume of Object_1 resulted from Step 1

```
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(Object_1.data)
bm.calc_volume(signed=True)
```

[image]

(3) Exporting Object_1 resulted from Step 1 as an STL file and then importing it (importedObject) back.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out!
In this case, the object that is generated from a boolean operation should go through a [triangulation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/triangulate.html).